# How can be found from which repository package has been installed if source was purged from source list

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, apt-cache

I have several repositories listed in my source list and some ppa added as sources

Can I know from which one specific package has been installed?

It is still possible if after installation repository was removed from source list?

Comment: Thanks, partially yes. Unfortunately i can't find information how to proceed if ppa was purged from system

Comment: @kakabomba Then you'd probably want to re-add this PPA and purge it correctly so it also remove the packages it installed. Next time you could start asking your real question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @xangua How can I re-add PPA if i don't know which one?

Comment: "I have several repositories listed in my source list and some ppa added as sources" You can start by detailing which repositories you added/removed, please consider EDIT your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apt-cache`:

```
apt-cache policy <your_package_name>
```

After the removal of the repository, you can't access this information.

---

*Example*

```
% apt-cache policy atom
atom:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.0-1~webupd8~0
  Version table:
     1.0.0-1~webupd8~0 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages

% sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-atom-vivid.list
% sudo apt-get update

% apt-cache policy atom                                              
N: Unable to locate package atom
```

Comment: @solsTiCe not necessarily. Nothing prevents the PPA owners from using the same key to sign a hundred PPAs.

Comment: thanks. IMO this is apt system imperfection, but ok

Comment: Wait a minute ... so the real answer is: *No, this isn't possible*?